# Did Nat King Cole express contempt for fans of his pop recordings?

Tags: history, jazz, pop, recording

It seems to me that I've seen [Nat King Cole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_King_Cole) quoted to this effect: I know that my Jazz records are good and my Pop records are junk. But how can I turn down the money I can make with the Pop records and with audiences that clearly don't know good or bad music when they hear it?

Am I recalling correctly? I'd like to track this attitude down. When and where did he express this sort of attitude?

- Here's a good example of one of his 'pop' recordings: ["Smile"](https://youtu.be/TAjx0d-fda4),
- and one of his 'jazz' recordings (on piano): ["Indiana"](https://youtu.be/Ymu8XwsVdo0).